# Integral of the form $ xe^{f(x)} $

Tags: integration, gaussian-integral

Does anyone know or can achieve a nicer solution for the integral of the form

$$ f(y, \gamma) = \frac{ 1 }{ \sqrt{ 2\pi } } \frac{ 1 }{ 2\sqrt{3} } \int_{ -\sqrt{3} }^{ \sqrt{3} } x e^{ - \frac{1}{2} (y - \sqrt{ \gamma }x )^{2} } dx $$ ?

I thought due to the form of the integral we can obtain a nice solution, however what I obtain is far from a nice solution. I've tried with a change of variable $ z = \frac{1}{ \sqrt{2} } ( y - \sqrt{ \gamma } x ) $ obtaining

$$ f(y, \gamma) = \frac{y}{2\gamma} \left[ \mathrm{erf} \left( \frac{ y + \sqrt{ 3\gamma } }{ \sqrt{2} } \right) - \mathrm{erf} \left( \frac{ y - \sqrt{ 3\gamma } }{ \sqrt{2} } \right) \right] + \frac{ \sqrt{2} }{ \sqrt{\pi} \gamma } e^{ - \frac{1}{2} y^{2} } e^{ - \frac{3}{2} \gamma } \sinh( \sqrt{ 3\gamma } y ) $$

This is the numerator of the non-linear estimator $ \mathrm{E}[x|y] $ for an additive scalar Gaussian channel ( $ y = \sqrt{ \gamma } x + n $ ) with an input uniformly distributed ( $ f(x) $ ) zero mean and variance normalized to unity.

I would like to compute the MMSE using Matlab. Although I know Matlab has the erf function already defined, I'm curious about If there exist a nice expression.

Comment: You could expand the exponent in place, take the constant $e^{-\frac 12 y^2}$ out and do an integration by parts of the remainder...

Comment: @abiessu but I must choose $ dv = x $ and $ v = \frac{x^{2}}{2} $ since we don't know how to integrate $ e^{- x^{2} } $ and the result is an integral even more complicated, do I mistaken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring the constants, by a linear change of variable you can split the integral in two terms

$$\int ue^{-u^2}du$$ and $$\int e^{-u^2}du,$$ with general bounds.

The first one is elementary, while the second is known to require the error function.

So no better solution.

Comment: yes is what I've done.

Comment: My point is that as your integrand can be reduced to a Gaussian between arbitrary bounds, there is nothing you can do, otherwise the error function would have a closed form.